# Streamlit & Session States (for Python & Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

With Python I’m developing a Streamlit app for recording feedback for student assignments. Displayed on the app’s main page are rows from a csv displaying each student’s grades and info. On the sidebar are text input boxes for providing comments. The goal for the app is to write the contents of the text input boxes into a new csv column, `final_comment`. I’m attempting to use a session state for the sidebar. However, I’m running to persistent errors with initializing the session state. Docs for initializing session state are [here](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/session_state_api.html).

Here’s the app design:

[image]

Here’s my working code, with the problem lines indicated with `<<<`:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Streamlit formatting
st.set_page_config(layout="wide")
st.header("Demo - Level 3.8.2 (Prototype)")
st.header("Text Display")
st.subheader("Below are the submissions and grades for each student. You can use the grading interface to the left to make adjustments to the final grade. Be sure to match the correct grade field with the corresponding text.")
form = st.sidebar.form(key='comments')
submit_button = form.form_submit_button(label='Submit Final Comments')

# Data displayed from csv via Pandas
df = pd.read_csv("Control2.csv", usecols=['last_name', 'feedback_number', 'word_count_score', 'composition_score', 'engagement_grade', 'total_score'])
df_name = pd.read_csv("Control2.csv", usecols=['first_name', 'last_name'])
number = len(df_name['last_name'])

# display single row from csv with values

def display_grades():
    for grade in range(number):
        st.table(df.iloc[grade:(grade+1)])

display_grades()

# display text_input boxes and student names in sidebar
for users in range(number):
    feedback_identifier = 'Final Comment: ' + df_name['first_name'][users] + " " + df_name['last_name'][users]
    feedback_salutation = df_name['first_name'][users] + ",\n\n"
    rb = form.text_area(feedback_identifier, value=feedback_salutation)

# writing data in session state
if submit_button:
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['data'])
    st.write(st.session_state.name0)    # <<< this initializes the session state
    #Find out which items in the session state have name
    for item in st.session_state:    # <<< this loops the session states
        if "name" in item:
            df = df.append({'data': st.session_state[item]}, ignore_index=True)

    df2 = pd.read_csv("Control2.csv")

    df2["final_comment"] = df

    df2.to_csv("Control2.csv", index=False)

    df2
```

The following error occurs when attempting to click `submit_button`:

```
AttributeError: st.session_state has no attribute "name0". Did you forget to initialize it?

Traceback:

File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 350, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\Streamlit\Experiment_3_8_2.py", line 43, in <module>
    st.write(st.session_state.name0)File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\state\session_state.py", line 549, in __getattr__
    return state.__getattr__(key)File "c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\streamlit\state\session_state.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(_missing_attr_error_message(key))
```

I'm really at a loss on how to proceed, as I don't understand why the session states won't initialize. Any insights or assistance would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Hi there. The problem is that `st.session_state.name0` is looking for a variable called `name0` within your session state variables. But there is none, as you did not initialize it. Could you provide a minimal working data set for `df` so that your code runs? Thanks